ADF Scheduling to stop overlapping pipelines
I am trying to create a pipeline that runs every 15 minutes, but I want to avoid overlapping the pipelines, so that in the instances of it taking longer than the expected 15 minutes, we have a backlog of queued pipelines.
Therefore, I have also tried a tumbling window trigger, this works great when the process takes > 15 minutes. However, if for example, it takes 5 minutes, it kicks the next pipeline off. Is there anyway I can avoid this, so that it only runs every 15 minutes or greater, without queuing?
Example of the expected pipeline outcome, without queuing.



pipelineid
pipelinename
run start
run end
status




1
realtimeLoad
2024-04-08 09:00:00
2024-04-08 09:13:00



2
realtimeLoad
2024-04-08 09:15:00
2024-04-08 09:33:00



3
realtimeLoad
2024-04-08 09:33:00
2024-04-08 09:45:00






Do you have a centralized data store/database that can store the execution state of pipelines? It could be just setting a flag. When the pipeline starts, it check the flag first and only execute if the flag is not set; and also clear the flag after finishing the job.

You can use a tumbling window itself for your requirement, as it supports self-dependency triggers. Here are the settings you can provide in the trigger:

Select the type of trigger as TumblingWindowTrigger
Add the required start date.
Add recurrence as every 15 mins
Add dependencies by expanding the advanced section.
Add the same trigger in the dependency. Give -15 mins in the offset. This will make sure the current trigger will depend on the previous 15 mins window.

Trigger settings:


When I run the trigger for one of my pipeline, it got executed only in the next 15 mins window.



I can't seem to replicate this, I have copied the tumbling window as per your screenshots, but my pipeline still runs, once the previous finishes (albeit with a 12second delay).
Type: TumblingWindowTrigger
Dependency added with offset -0.00:15:00
Delay 00:00:00
Max Concurrency: 1
Retry policy 0

Could you share the trigger definition?

Screenshot or Json of trigger.

I created a second version of the trigger, that has worked, thanks.
